# Using hyperlink within sharepoint listview

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, hyperlink

I know I can use sharepoint designer to convert list to data view wp and then i can do this easily. but I wanted to if there was a way to do this with list view wp without intervention of sp designer.

I have a order table

```
orderid  orderdate  
1        1/1/2011
2        2/2/2012
3        3/3/2013
```

I like to establish hyperlink to the orderid values where it will go it's correspondence page. for example, you are on the list view page for

http://server/Lists/Orders/Allitems.aspx

then I like to see the orderids are hyperlinked. so when user clicks on order id 2 it will take user to

http://server/ordersite/2/order.aspx

Comment: "Emerg3ncy" - this isn't a chat room to show off how clever you are with ascii art

Answer (score 0):

You can use Christophes method to generate HTML in a calculated column and then javascript to turn the 'escaped' html into 'real' html.

e.g.

```
="<a href='http://server/ordersite/" & ID & "/order.aspx">Show Order</a>"
```

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-window-or-not/

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I can certainly try this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm, this approach will not work as calculated field type does not support lookup column or id column.

Comment: I've tested this on WSS3.0 and SPF 2010 and it works fine - the ID column doesn't show in teh "Insert Column" list but you can type it in manually (make sure its all upper case)